# Bootstrap icon replace in audio player

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, html5-audio

I have an audio player, which is now working on "PLAY" & "PAUSE"
Now I want to replace this Play(text) & Pause(text) to bootstrap icons.
Check it out on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8dzd6bh4/)

**HTML**

```
<audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
    <source src='http://freshly-ground.com/data/audio/mpc/20090119%20-%20Untitled%20Groove.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>
<a href="#" id="audioControl">play!</a>
```

**JS**

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'play!' : 'pause!';

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use bootstrap icon add this link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

HTML

```
 <audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
        <source src='http://freshly-ground.com/data/audio/mpc/20090119%20-%20Untitled%20Groove.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
    </audio>
    <a href="#"  ><span id="audioControl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></a>
```

JS

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {


if(ctrl.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle") {
        ctrl.className="glyphicon glyphicon-pause";
       yourAudio["play"]();
}
else if (ctrl.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-pause"){

     ctrl.className="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle";
    yourAudio["pause"]();

}
};
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8dzd6bh4/2/

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use [Bootstrap's glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). You can do the following:

```
<a href="#" id="audioControl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
```

Comment: Play icon working good but when I play audio is not pausing nor the pause icon change to play.

Comment: You will have to write some code to react to the button click using an if/else statement. This can be done using jQuery or plain JavaScript. However, what you want is the class name to change upon clicking so that the pause/play glyph switches each time.